# Absolute positioning makes elements inside a scrollable div container overlap. How to fix it?

Tags: html, css

This is my first (reworked) post here, so I apologize in advance for any inconvenience caused.

I am working on a website featuring a header, footer, sticky navigation sidebar, and scrolling content. I am stuck on the following problem though: Inside the scrolling div, there are some text paragraphs (`<div id="text-bottom">`) that should be aligned to the bottom of the wrapper (`<div id="main">`) Instead of using the margin or padding properties to generate a fixed amount of space around the content, I intended to make those paragraphs responsive, so they always stick to the bottom, regardless of the screen size and orientation of the visitor’s device.

I read on multiple forum threads that the trick behind this is to bottom align the child div (in my case, the text paragraphs mentioned above) with `position: absolute` while making sure that the parent wrapper has `position: relative`. However, using absolute positioning creates an overlap (noticeable on smaller desktop screens and mobile media queries) of the elements inside the scrollable div. How can I prevent absolute position from overlapping? Do you have any suggestions on how to fix that? Unfortunately, I am not authorized to change the .HTML part. Here is also a dummy version of my website: https://codepen.io/Lahabrea/pen/JjvVJxR

```css
@import url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@xz/fonts@1/serve/hk-grotesk.min.css");
* {
  font-family: "HK Grotesk", sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#all {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  grid-template-areas: "header header header header" "subnav haupt haupt haupt" "footer footer footer footer";
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 130px 1fr 30px;
}

#subnavigation_float {
  grid-area: subnav;
}

#main {
  grid-area: haupt;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border-left: 1px solid;
  color: var(--dark);
  padding: 0px 160px 0px 0px;
  position: relative;
  height: 1fr;
}

#text {
  width: 640px;
  position: relative;
  top: 8px;
  background-color: beige;
}

#text-bottom {
  width: 640px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}
```

```html
<div id="all">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="text-bottom">
      <h2>Text Header</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="subnavigation_float">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="blank.com">Button 1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 workarounds in mind. One is to set a `padding-bottom` for `#main` with the same value as the height of the `#text-bottom` with `position: absolute`. But it works only if the height is fixed, which probably is not always the case.

The other is to use `display:flex` for the container `#main` and set `justify-content: space-between;` to force the children to stick to the top and bottom of the container. Then you don't need to set the position of `#text-bottom` to `absolute`. Here is how:

```css
@import url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@xz/fonts@1/serve/hk-grotesk.min.css");
* {
  font-family: "HK Grotesk", sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#all {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  grid-template-areas: "header header header header" "subnav haupt haupt haupt" "footer footer footer footer";
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 130px 1fr 30px;
}

#subnavigation_float {
  grid-area: subnav;
}

#main {
grid-area: haupt;
overflow: auto;
overflow-y: scroll;
border-left: 1px solid var(--dark);
color: var(--dark);
padding: 8px 160px 0px 8px;
position: relative;

display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: space-between;
}

#text {
  width: 640px;
  position: relative;
  top: 8px;
  background-color: beige;
}

#text-bottom {
  width: 640px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}
```

```html
<div id="all">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="text-bottom">
      <h2>Text Header</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="subnavigation_float">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="blank.com">Button 1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```